# How do I send multiple request to let the client know that upload and processing has finished?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out how I can send multiple requests to let the client know that uploading and processing has finished.

For example: Let the client know that upload has finished, and processing has started. When processing has been finished, send another request to notify the client.

I only want to know the proper functions to use because it seems that sending two res.write()'s wont send until I call res.end()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually want to inform the client about updates that happen asynchronously on the server / in the backend.

From the top of my head, there are a few ways to achieve getting asynchronous information to the client:

1. Open a stream and push updates via the stream to the client ([for example, using server-sent-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934831/nodejs-express-stream-stdout-instantly-to-the-client))
2. Open a websocket and push your messages to the client (you need to manage the HTTP and websocket connections to write to the correct one)
3. Create a new route to let clients subscribe to information about the status of a job ([some example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53798260/update-message-in-view-after-view-has-been-rendered-in-express-once-asynchrono/53798842#53798842))

I'd select one of the solutions depending on your current client design. If you have something like websockets already available, I'd use that - but it's quite something to setup, if you don't. Streaming might not work cross-browser, but is quite easy to build. For the third option, you probably need more housekeeping in order to not create some memory leaks if a client disconnects.

Comment: One of those should work. I just didn't know the proper term for it. Thank you!